<mat-form-field> component doesn't work properly with FormArray and formGroupName
The input field is not displayed with the appearance of <mat-form-field> before clicking inside when formGroupName is used with FormArray.
See the example:
TS:
formMain = this.fb.group({
    details: this.fb.array([
      new FormGroup({
        label: new FormControl(''),
        description: new FormControl(''),
      }),
    ]),
  });

  get detailsFormArray() {
    return this.formMain.controls.details as FormArray;
  }

  addDetails() {
    this.detailsFormArray.push(this.fb.control(''));
  }
}

HTML:
<form [formGroup]="formMain">
  <div formArrayName="details">
    <div
      *ngFor="let detail of detailsFormArray.controls; index as i"
      [formGroupName]="i"
    >
      <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Label of a detail</mat-label>
        <input id="detail-label" matInput type="text" formControlName="label" />
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Description of a detail</mat-label>
        <input
          id="detail-description"
          matInput
          type="text"
          formControlName="description"
        />
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<br />

<button type="button" (click)="addDetails()">+ Add Details</button>


and

Is there a solution to this problem?

You are not adding the FormGroup instance to details FormArray correctly. Currently, you are adding the FormControl instance.
Would recommend writing a shared function to create the FormGroup instance.
formMain = this.fb.group({
  details: this.fb.array([this.addDetailsFormGroup()]),
});

addDetails() {
  this.detailsFormArray.push(this.addDetailsFormGroup());
}

addDetailsFormGroup() {
  return new FormGroup({
    label: new FormControl(''),
    description: new FormControl(''),
  });
}

Demo @ StackBlitz

Hi Yong Shun, thanks for the solution and the explanation. It works perfectly!
